# How to correct a ' sting literal in condition' warning in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
def cafeteria 
  puts "The cafeteria is a mess, as you walk into the kitchen all the pots and pans are all      over the floor."
  puts " The freever is open, everything has spoiled, and it smells awful!"
  puts "At the far end of the kitchen a set of knives is lying on the floor."
  puts "What do you do?"
  prompt()
  action = gets.chomp                           
  if action.include? 'knife' or 'knives'
    puts "Yes! now you have a weapon."
    puts "Now what?"
  elsif action == "leave."
    return :hallway
  else 
    puts "I don't understand."
    return :death
  end
end
```

Comment: You should include some text(not just title) to explain the problem and not just paste in code, what have you tried so far? etc...http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action.include? 'knife' or 'knives'` will always yield truth value. (even though there's no `kinfe`, `knives` in the string)

```
action = 'asdf'
# => "asdf"
action.include? 'knife' or 'knives'
# => "knives"
```

because it is interpreted as `(action.include? 'knife') or 'knives'`

Maybe you mean following?

```
action.include? 'knife' or action.include? 'knives'
# => false
```